# area fill width to all container area

Tags: css, flexbox, angular-material-7

I have this situation:

[image]

In the left I have a tree with my companies and in the right a DIV with div which I will draw my matCard (angular material).

I would like that MyCard div can fill all with margin of 30px.

If I set two matCards second one will be under MyCard with 30px of margin between them.

How can I do it using CSS? to fill MyCArd to all myMainDi vwith 30px of margin. If I change width length that card change the with automatically.Thx

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the width of the card to 100% which will make it fill in the space. Then also set the margin to your 30px to keep the space on the edge.

I think it would help if you shared your html and current css.